# PHP give a different class if there is more than an amount of blocks

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I've been working on a website and it has 5 blocks. When the screen gets smaller I need to get 2 of the blocks under the other 3 and they get a different with so i gave them another class.

Im trying to get it into a CMS and i have to use this code down below.
Now is my question how do i make this happen with if i want the user to be able to edit the blocks. I've tried to make some edits in the script but so far no succes. I need to add a different class to block nr 4 and 5. What is a good way to do this?

```
<div class="colums">
    <?php
    $i=1;
    //krsort($properties['blocks']);
    foreach($properties['blocks'] as $block)
    {
        echo '<div class="colum1" id="pic'.$i.'" style="background-image:url(/uploaded/overige/'.$block['image2'].');">
            <div class="content_colum">
                <div class="wilpe_logo">
                    <a href="'.$cms->make_link($block['link']).'"><img src="/uploaded/overige/'.$block['image'].'" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="text_holder">
                    '.$block['text'].'
                    <div class="button_two">
                        <a class="button_text" href="'.$cms->make_link($block['link']).'">'.$block['linktext'].'</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Colum1 needs to be colum2 if there is 3 colum1's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer in another question. I made the question smaller and more understandable and this is the answer that came out:

```
    $i = 1;
foreach($properties['blocks'] as $block)
{
    echo '<div class="' . ($i < 4 ? 'colum1' : 'colum2') . '" id="pic'.$i.'" style="background-image:url(/uploaded/overige/'.$block['image2'].');">
// --------------
```

[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717472/change-classname-if-i-is-a-certain-number#35717488)

Posted it here to share with everyone.