# Change classname if i is a certain number

Tags: php, html

Im looking for a way to change the number in a class if i=4 or higher.

```
        $i=1;
    foreach($properties['blocks'] as $block)
    {
        echo '<div class="colum1" id="pic'.$i.'" style="background-image:url(/uploaded/overige/'.$block['image2'].');">
```

Is there any way to do this ? colum1 needs to become colum2. i've been trying to use things like if else etc. but so far no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($properties['blocks'] as $block)
{
    echo '<div class="' . ($i < 4 ? 'colum1' : 'colum2') . '" id="pic'.$i.'" style="background-image:url(/uploaded/overige/'.$block['image2'].');">
// --------------
```

Comment: Thanks i'm not sure what i did wrong but this is working.